# What is the method used for finding the edges of a cover graph given an Interval Order?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

[image: Figure 3: The interval order graph given]

I am having trouble understanding how to come up with the edges for the cover graph represented by some interval order.

```
The answer to the question is: 
(a, b),(a, g),(b, c),(b, e),(b, h)),(d, e),
(d, h),(d, j),(g, c),(g, f),(g, h),(g, j),
(i, c),(i, f),(i, h),(i, j),(e, f),(e, j).
```

I do not understand why (a,j) is not a part of this. I also am slightly confused by the method you use to find these edges. If they are intersecting, doesn't it mean that they are parts of an anti-chain? Otherwise, they are a connected chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cover graph $G_{P}=(P,E)$ relative to a poset $P$ is such that $(i,j)\in E$ iff $i<j$ and there is no $x$ such that $i<x<j.$
In your case $a<e<j$ so $(a,j)$ is not there.